# swift keep data updated

Tags: swift, sqlite, swiftui

I'm making an app for adding and showing contacts. I'd like to update my view when I save a contact.

This is my code to get all users in sqlite:

```
public mutating func getUsers() -> [ContactEntity] {
     
    var userModels: [ContactEntity] = []
    users = users.order(id.desc)

    do {
 
        for user in try db.prepare(users) {
 
            let userModel: ContactEntity = ContactEntity()
            userModel.id = user[id]
            userModel.name = user[name]
            userModel.number = user[number]
            userModel.placemeet = user[placemeet]
            
            userModels.append(userModel)
        }
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    return userModels
}
```

this is my view model:

```
private var dbManager: DBManager = DBManager()

@Published var user: [ContactEntity]

init(){
    self.user = dbManager.getUsers()
}
```

and this the code to show all contacts in the view:

```
List(viewModel.user){ user in
            ListContactRow(userContact: user)
}
```

Comment: add `self.user = dbManager.getUsers()` line at end of the save contact function.

Comment: Are you using some 3rd party library to access SQLite? If so then check if it has some functionality to subscribing to updates.

Answer (score 0):

You have to mark your viewModel as an ObservableObject.

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    ...
}
```

And the instance has to have the property wrapper @ObservableObject.

```
@ObservedObject var viewModel = ViewModel()
```

Then the view should update on every change of an @Published variable in the viewModel.